# How can encrypt the kafka password in jaas configuration file

Tags: spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am new to Kafka, please let me know how can we encrypt the password used in jaas configuration file.
My config example.

```
KafkaClient { 

  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required

  username="username"

  password="password";

};
```

I am using VM arguments to fetch the config file in the spring boot application.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The next best, more robust algorithm that you might want to consider is [SASL SCRAM](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl_scram):

> Salted Challenge Response Authentication Mechanism (SCRAM) is a family
> of SASL mechanisms that addresses the security concerns with
> traditional mechanisms that perform username/password authentication
> like PLAIN and DIGEST-MD5. The mechanism is defined in RFC 5802. Kafka
> supports SCRAM-SHA-256 and SCRAM-SHA-512 which can be used with TLS to
> perform secure authentication. The username is used as the
> authenticated Principal for configuration of ACLs etc. The default
> SCRAM implementation in Kafka stores SCRAM credentials in Zookeeper
> and is suitable for use in Kafka installations where Zookeeper is on a
> private network. Refer to Security Considerations for more details.

**IMPORTANT: If you decide to go ahead, make sure you are using TLS, else there is little to no benefits.**